# Confusion over Implementation of Business Logic in Clean Architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, clean-architecture

I have spent the last 2 weeks trying to understand and implement Clean Architecture in a new app. I've read Robert Martin's blog article on the subject, as well as many other articles - each with their own take on it, which has now left me a bit confused.

Please bear in mind that I'm not as yet clued up on deeper DDD principles such as bounded contexts, value objects, etc, so I'm trying to keep this design (and my initial understanding) as simple as possible. I've tried to use the Repository/UnitOfWork pattern and here is what my Visual Studio solution currently looks like (I've simplified it a bit for brevity):

```
[MyApp.Core]
    [Entities]
        Student.cs
        Course.cs
    [Exceptions]
    [Interfaces]
        [Repositories]
            IStudentRepository.cs
            ICourseRepository.cs
        IGenericRepository.cs
        IUnitOfWork.cs
    [DTOs]
        CourseInputModel.cs
        CourseNameResponseModel.cs
        StudentsInCoursesResponseModel.cs
    [Services/UsesCases] <=== ??? not sure how to implement this 

[MyApp.Infrastructure]
    [Repositories]
        GenericRepository.cs
        CourseRepository.cs
        StudentRepository.cs
    MyApplicationDbContext.cs
    UnitOfWork.cs

[MyApp.Api]
    [Controllers]
        IndexController.cs
```

My aim is to achieve the following:

1. To have a repository class (inherited from a base/generic repository class) for each domain object.
2. I want my repositories to only return domain entities and not DTOs/ViewModels.
3. Controller methods in the API project should *not* call the repositories directly.
4. Controller methods in the API project should *not* contain any business logic - at the most they should accept a ViewModel as a request object, pass that on to some broker or intermediary class which can then run any validations or custom business logic and return a custom response object (not a domain entity) back to the controller method which it will simply present in the response.
5. The business logic service or broker should reside in the `Core` project as it is central to the rules of the business application. `Infrastructure` will hence only contain implementations of contracts created in `Core`.

IUnitOfWork looks like this:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    ICourseRepository Courses { get; }
    IStudentRepository Students { get; }
    int Complete();
}
```

I had thought of implementing `UseCaseHandlers` in my `Core` project as such:

```
public class CourseListHandler
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;

    public CourseListHandler(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        _uow = uow;
    }

    public List<CourseNameResponseModel> Execute()
    {
        using (_uow)
        {
            return _uow.Courses
                .GetAll()
                .Select(s => new CourseNameResponseModel() {
                    Id = s.Id,
                    Name = s.Name,
                    Level = s.Level
                })
                .OrderBy(o => o.Name)
                .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

This would then be injected into the relevant controller class, and called in one of the action methods. I chose to use UnitOfWork as I feel that it would allow me the opportunity to work with multiple repository objects in a single transaction, should the need arise (and it will).

**Questions:**

1. I understand that this is subjective, but am I going about this the right/wrong way? What do you suggest I change or think about differently?
2. Am I abstracting too much - in terms of using UnitOfWork, and also outsourcing the business logic to another service/handler?
3. Am I disposing the correct object, and am I doing so correctly?
4. The `CourseListHandler` above just handles a **single** use case of getting a simplified list of courses from the storage mechanism. Seeing that this is for an API, each action in a controller (endpoint) could potentially have many Use Case handlers, and the amount of UseCaseHandler classes that would need to be injected into a controller would become ridiculously large. I know that SOLID principles teach us that a class in this scenario should be responsible for doing only one thing, but is this not considered "over-engineering"?
5. Stemming from 4, would it not be better to have a "Service" class instead of a UseCaseHandler that had multiple methods that would suit the needs of every potential action in a given controller?

I know these are very amateur questions to ask, and yes, I should be reading up on it more, but honestly, the more I do read up on it, the more I come across vastly different takes on implementing clean architecture. Your insight on this as a StackExchange member would be invaluable to me and is highly appreciated!

This is not a .NET Core solution - it is using .NET framework 4.7, and I plan to use use Unity for DI/IoC.

Comment: I flagged this as primarily-opinion-based per your own acknowledgement. That being said, the service class you mention in #5 is what I would personally do, sort of. I have seen stuff like this commonly implemented in "Manager" classes that handle functionality that is related to some sort of logical grouping. The easiest way to code in this manner is to think about real entities. For instance, when you go the Registration office, you talk to an Agent (or manager) who can do things for you like give you a list of classes and register you. You can then inject this class into your controller.

Comment: Hi Juan. Thank you for your comment

Comment: You may get a good answer on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I generally agree with @JuanR here but would also add that the single responsibility principle doesn't mean it does _exactly_ one thing.  Think of the common example of a car steering wheel.  It doesn't _just_ turn left. More broadly it is responsible for steering in general which includes turning left but also turning right or even maintaining a straight course.

Comment: A pattern is not necessarily something you *have to* write code for. It's something you must know and most of the time, just be able to recognize amongst the computer mists. In modern environments (C#, etc.) it's generally there and you can use it w/o any additional effort or abstraction (ie: unit of work => ADO transaction, Entity Framework, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Wow, that's a lot let me try to answer these in order.

1. I think in general you have A better idea than most.  I would look at your core project and try to define your domain models As either entities or value objects. Of course, you might already be doing this without looking at the code I can't evaluate either way.
   a.  Also, I would expect your API's to own your data transfer objects. I would not expect those to be all the way down in your core project.
2. The idea of whether or not to abstract out the unit of work pattern is one I've seen people go back and forth on if you're in C sharp and you're already using entity framework there might be little to be gained from implementing the unit of work pattern yourself though if you ever decide to go with another ORM (object-relational mapper) then having it abstracted yourself doesn't tie your project to entity framework or any other ORM.
   a.  Abstracting to a service might be correct it depends on the situation oftentimes I find that I can put a lot of my logic in the domain models themselves.  in those cases the domain models know that they can save things like a student can add a class to itself but the implementation of how that is actually achieved is not the concern up the domain model it just simply broadcasts at an event saying John Smith has added algebra Level 3. and your repository should be set up in such a way to be able to intercept and save that event correctly.
3. I can't see your implementation of your disposable. so I can't tell if you're doing it correctly. but in general, you have it right that your repository should make sure that your database context is disposed of just making sure that as you implement the interface it is actually doing that.
4. your 4th question is related to the up the solid design principles if you follow up in his book clean clode or most of his YouTube videos uncle Bob normally gives an understanding then what I feel most people teach on the subject . his argument is not that a class needs to only do one thing but it only needs to be responsible to one person So it's clearly OK to have a student repository add students take away students, update students, and elite students you don't need to create a separate class or handler for each one of those cases just different methods. his argument is that there's ultimately one person in a business who can cause change to that code and make sure that each class basically has one master.  again take a look at the S of solid designs and either uncle Bob spoke clean architecture or watch one of his many YouTube videos.
5. yes I think in this case having a service is correct. you might also look at the tool “mediator” it helps split up these concerns.

So there's a lot to cover here and you know that as well. I would take a deep dive into looking at an understanding of the differences between and value objects that will help you guide a lot of the way you build your core application. also in general just think about where are your dependencies are going. this is the heart of DDD design. and is in opposition to many of the design patterns that you will see out there like traditional tiered or 3 tier web apps.  let your code the core of your project take as few dependencies as possible preferably 0. This will prevent your web transfer objects or your database from influencing your code. like you said you still have a lot to learn about DDD but it's clear that you're getting the basics

Comment: Thank you Wizardhammer. Please allow me some time to go through your answer this evening and I'll reply here if I have any questions.

Comment: It's a lot to learn and it is a fundamentally different paradigm then we others are used to.  You might get more traction with this over at the https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ site. 

I found it to be more helpful when persons ask this type of question.